# How Cassandra handle duplicated data when reading from SSTable

Tags: cassandra, datastax

In Datastax's [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlWriteUpdate.html), it said:

> During a write, Cassandra adds each new row to the database without
>   checking on whether a duplicate record exists. This policy makes it
>   possible that **many versions of the same row** may exist in the database.

As far as I understand, that means there are possibly more than 1 non-compacted SSTables that contains different versions of the same row. How does Cassandra handle duplicated data when it read data from these SSTables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@quangh : As already stated in document :

`This is why Cassandra performs another round of comparisons during a read process. When a client requests data with a particular primary key, Cassandra retrieves many versions of the row from one or more replicas. The version with the most recent timestamp is the only one returned to the client ("last-write-wins").`

All the writes operation have a timestamp associated. In this case different node will have different version of same row. But during read operation Cassandra will pick row with latest timestamp. I hope this solves your query.